# Can user starts an application with screen off?

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

In my application I check to the server some user state in the onCreate() method of the main activity.

I recently notice that doing so is an issue when I run the app from Eclipse while the phone is asleep (screen off, locked). In this situation, the application waits that the screen get unlocked to call the onStart() method and pursue its way. That makes fail the data update.

Maybe I should put it inside onStart?

Can the user do the same process = start an app with locked screen? I though of Tasker but are there other way?

Edit: All the server updates communication are done off main thread, handled by managing classes and I use volley. So it's not a service and though I will put one later, I have not enough time to do it now. Except if you say it's 2 days work to learn and implement. Can a user start an application like a dev can do it ?

Comment: have you considered the option of using a Service ?

Comment: yes I considered it and will implement one. But it's too late now for this incoming release. Thoughts about my question ?

Comment: I can't think of any other method. Service won't take much of your time. You can implement that in a couple of hours only. It would be reliable also.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will give it a shoot maybe just to see.

Answer (score 0):

This things that you are doing in an Activity must surely be performed in a `Service`. Android `Service` provides you with doing background data processing/syncing.